# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Trying to put XML into a List

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have to following XML code witch I like to convert into a List with keys and values:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<root>
<command>getClient</command>
<id>10292</id>
</root>
```

My C# code is like this:

```
XElement aValues = XElement.Parse(sMessage);
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> oValues = aValues.Element("root").Elements().Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(e.Name.ToString(), e.Value)).ToList();
```

sMessage is the XML string.

Now I'm getting the following error, and I can not figure out why:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: One of your objects is null. Use the debugger to see which line the exception is on, then check each value for null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"root"` is your `aValues` element. So, there is no `"root"` elements in children of `aValue`, and  `aValues.Element("root")` gives you `null`.

Correct query:

```
 aValue.Elements()
       .Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(e.Name.LocalName, e.Value))
       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Element("root").Elements()` just use `aValues.Descendants()`.In this case `aValues` is already your root element.You are looking for `root` inside of `root` so it returns `null`. BTW, you can use a `Dictionary` instead of `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`

```
var oValues = aValues.Descendants()
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => (object) x);
```